# Signed out but still says "G'day John"

Tags: ebay, cookies, cache, logout

I signed out of eBay, but the site still says "G'day John" next to the sign in link (let's assume my name is John). I do not want to have to reset cache, cookies and website data etc. just to clear my name from there.

How do I stop it from showing this?

Comment: It seems there is no other way besides deleting cookies for eBay.
The site continues to show suggestions based on my purchases and searches even after I have signed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to delete your ebay cookies one time.

When you log in, be sure "Stay signed in" is not checked.

If "G'day John" is still there after you log off, you will need to delete the ebay related cookies one time.
How to depends on the browser, but on Firefox you can delete individual site cookies. Other data stored by the browser should not affect this.